# Flutter run Not working When i use command flutter run?

Tags: flutter, dart

i have faced a problem when i try to run app. its like showing.

"Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 96.0.4664.93 Edge (web)   • edge   • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 96.0.1054.43 If you would like your app to run on web, consider running `flutter create .` to generate projects for these platforms."

problem will show only git clone templates . i'm using windows 10

Comment: Does `flutter` command work? Then run `flutter doctor -v` to check the errors.

Comment: Connected device (2 available)
    • Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 96.0.4664.93
    • Edge (web)   • edge   • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 96.0.1054.43

• No issues found! everything is fine. but i didn't get out put . when  i try to  run terminal showing

Comment: Which platform are you trying to run on?

The message you're given suggest you're trying to run the project as a web-app and the project doesn't have this support added to it.

Try and start your android emulator and then do the run command again.

Comment: use `flutter run -d c` to run with Chrome

Comment: same issues when i run on physical device . Is there any commands for running physical device?